# Lapack, DGEEV does not give me the right eigenvalues

Tags: fortran, lapack

When trying to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix with the [DGEEV](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html) function, I noticed that they were non conjugate and thus wrong.

I tried testing with the simple (0 1; -1 0) matrix (which has eigenvalues i and -i), but it doesn't give me the right solution.

Can someone point me to the error in my code?

```
program myProgram
    real(kind=dp), dimension(2) :: ew_real, ew_imag, ev
    real(kind=dp), dimension(4*5,4*5) :: work 
    integer info
    real(kind=dp), DIMENSION(2, 2) :: array
    array = reshape((/ 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0/), shape(array))      

    call DGEEV('N','V',2,array,2,ew_real,ew_imag,ev,2,ev,2,work,size(work,1),info)
end program
```

Output of my program:
(0.00000,0.00000) and (0.00000,-0.40824)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! `work` is supposed to be a 1D array, not a 2D array. DGEEV() is usually called twice : once to performe a workspace query, then `work` is allocated to the optimal size, then a second call to DGEEV() is performed to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors. See https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/dgeev_ex.f.htm par instance. Could you print the return value of `ìnfo`? It provides an insight on the reason why the call to DGEEV() failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mistakes

1. The `ev` array is only of `dimension(2)` whereas it should be of `dimension(2,2)`.
2. `work` should be a one-dimensional array of length `4n=4*2`.

Note that the first one actually corrupts your memory and thus, you get the wrong eigenvalues.

### Improvement

Moreover, you should be using the `lapack95` module which gives generic interfaces that are easier to call.

The following example shows both calls

```pascal
program main
  use iso_fortran_env, only: dp => real64
  use lapack95

  integer                       :: info
  real(kind=dp), dimension(2)   :: ew_real, ew_imag
  real(kind=dp), dimension(4*2) :: work
  real(kind=dp), dimension(2,2) :: array, ev_left, ev_right
  array = reshape([0, -1, 1, 0], shape(array))

  ! lapack
  call dgeev('N','V',2,array,2,ew_real,ew_imag,ev_left,2,ev_right,2,work,size(work),info)
  print *, 'eval1', cmplx(ew_real(1), y=ew_imag(1))
  print *, 'eval2', cmplx(ew_real(2), y=ew_imag(2))

  ! lapack95 call
  call geev(array, ew_real, ew_imag, vr=ev_right)
  print *, 'eval1', cmplx(ew_real(1), y=ew_imag(1))
  print *, 'eval2', cmplx(ew_real(2), y=ew_imag(2))
end program
```

The output is

```sh
$ ./main
 eval1               (0.0000000000000000,1.0000000000000000)
 eval2              (0.0000000000000000,-1.0000000000000000)
 eval1               (0.0000000000000000,1.0000000000000000)
 eval2              (0.0000000000000000,-1.0000000000000000)
```

Comment: Minor comment: I still tend to use the older interface because the lapack95 module wasn't available everywhere I looked, and my overarching aim in life is to minimise the number of emails from users - this was a few years back, hopefully things have changed since then.